# PHP MySQL PDO stored procedures and INOUT parameters

Tags: php, stored-procedures, pdo, mysql5

I am using some stored procedures against a datastore shared by more than one application and need to call a stored procedure that has an `INOUT` parameter.

From documentation this would work something like

```
$prob_param = null;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('CALL obnoxiousStoredProc(:problem_param)');
$stmt->bindParam(':problem_param', $prob_param, PDO::PARAM_INT|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 11);
$stmt->execute();
echo 'Prob param: ' . var_export($prob_param, true);
```

And we would see something like

```
Prob param: int(420)
```

BUT **There is a bug** that prevents this from working as expected [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502524/701368).

So instead we get

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1414 OUT or INOUT argument $parameter_number for routine $procedure_name is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable
```

The workaround, as described in the answer is two-fold, separate your input and output parameters (which I can get my DBA to do) and use local variables

e.g.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('CALL obnoxiousStoredProc(@problem_param)');
```

and then use a second query

```
SELECT @problem_param
```

To get your value.

**My question is: what is the scope of this "local variable" in PDO? Am I setting myself for a race condition if my php code is getting simultaneously?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> User-defined variables are connection-specific.

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html).

So no, there is no possibility of a race condition in a php execution context.

Comment: Thanks! Could I see any collisions with PDO's persistent connections?

Comment: You won't see a "collision"--the variable may have an old value, but your query will give it a new value anyway. That said, you should avoid persistent connections in MySQL because connection state may persist (e.g. table left locked, transaction left open, etc.), which is a subtle source of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('CALL obnoxiousStoredProc(@problem_param)');
$stmt->execute();

$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT @problem_param');
$stmt2->execute();
$var = $stmt->fetch();

var_dump($var)
```