# PHP calling stored proc MYSQL passing parameters

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have looked and tried but to no avail.  I have a SP in MYSQL proc( par1 )

When I pass SQL string `call proc(var1)`, the result is blank.  I can call proc from MYSQL and get results but not from PHP page.

I have looked at so many ways and such but nothing works.  does somebody have or can point me to example.  simple.  already have proc set and tested.

I can call SQL from PHP and get result sets just not from SP.

simple please

```
connect to DB
var = 2 ;
SQL = "call proc( $var ) "
call SQL/query with SQL
return result.  this particular sp only returns one row
```

the result is a recordset/rows of data.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Procedures, MySQL and PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118506/stored-procedures-mysql-and-php)

Comment: I am thoroughly confused.  I have been doing MSSQL & ASP.net/ASP for years.  I can do that stuff blindfolded.  As I look for examples to learn how to the PHP & MYSQL using Stored Procedure thing, it seems to be kind of vague.  I can easily from PHP execute a SQL statement but doing Stored Proc doesn't seem to be an easy option.  I see references to that one cannot trying with sqli and/or PDO .  what am I missing???

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Alex, thanks for replying....  I can't find an example

Comment: here is code that I use to extract rows from db w/o error.  however, if i set $SQL to call a SP and then try to output the rows i get NOTHING.

Comment: $result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();